# Labels with different values and with different coordination in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have done the coding the labels are appearing in the right coordinate. The problems that there is one label more that the number i post. Also, just one label whose showing the value. I want all of the showing different values?

```
//set the globals 

Random coor = new Random();
Label nodeLabel = new Label();
int xCoor;
int yCoor;

//set the button to show  the labels 

private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
    {
        //X Coordinate 
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            xCoor = coor.Next(0, 750);
        }

        //Y Coordinate
        for (int u = 0; u < 1; u++)
        {
            yCoor = coor.Next(0, 500);
        }

        //Set up the labels
        for (int l = 0; l < value; l++)
        {
            nodeLabel.Text = value + " ";
            nodeLabel.AutoSize = true;

            nodeLabel.Location = new Point(xCoor + 10, yCoor + 5);
        }
        this.Controls.Add(nodeLabel);
    }

}
```

See the line for  a picture of the running program
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Xn9.png

Comment: Where does `value` comes from?

Comment: What is the point of `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` ? The loop will run exactly once (i.e. it is pointless).

Comment: value it can be any  number,

Comment: and the for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) is for changing the coordinate of the label every-time I am pressing the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want 15 labels, how about:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int label_amount = 15;
int xCoor;
int yCoor;

private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //set the button to show  the labels 
    for (int x = 0; x < label_amount; x++)
    {
        xCoor = coor.Next(0, 750);
        yCoor = coor.Next(0, 500);

        Label nodeLabel = new Label();  
        nodeLabel.Text = value + " " + xCoor + "," + yCoor;
        nodeLabel.AutoSize = true;
        nodeLabel.Location = new Point(xCoor + 10, yCoor + 5);
        // Add your label to whatever you're adding it
    }
}
```

in your code you're just running weird loops which make no sense.

Comment: thanks alot. But what i am missing are: 1- the labels are not showing different values. 2- there is always one more label i do not know from where it come

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the wrong loop variable. It should be I or i or any other name of your choice instead of 1.

Where you defined the value variable, it is missing.

Comment: The value i am defined it using numericUpDown tool @moss